# First test passes while second test (with same data) fail Selenium with Codeception

Tags: codeception

I'm a noob trying to learn Codeception with the Selenium WebServer and have come across a problem I can't seem to find an answer to. I'm writing a super basic test that ensure the data passed in a from in index.php, is the same on another page, toupper.php.

This is my index.php:

```
<?php $something = "Can you see me?"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Convert Me!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Convert Me!</h1>
    <p>
      <?php echo $something; ?>
    </p>

    <form action="toupper.php" method="post" id="post_form">
      <label for="string">Convert to Uppercase:</label>
      <input type="text" name="my_string" id="string">

      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Convert">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my toupper.php:

```
<?php

  $message = (!empty($_POST['my_string'])) ?    strtoupper($_POST['my_string']) : "No string entered";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To Upper!</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>To Upper!</h1>

    <p class="message"><?php echo $message; ?></p>

    <p><a href="index.php">Back to form</a>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I've created a simple testsuite:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('ensure Toupper form works');
$I->amOnPage('index.php');
$I->see('Can you see me?');
$I->fillField('my_string', 'convert me to uppercase');
$I->click('Convert');
$I->amOnSubdomain('toupper.php');
$I->see('CONVERT ME TO UPPERCASE');
```

Now, whenever I run the test, the test passes, but when I run the exact test again with the same data, it fails. And I'm not using a database.

This is the error I get:

```
Scenario --
 I am on page "index.php"
 I see "Can you see me?"
 I fill field "my_string","convert me to uppercase"
 I click "Convert"
 I am on subdomain "toupper.php"
 I see "CONVERT ME TO UPPERCASE"
 FAIL

--------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 2.59 seconds, Memory: 8.00MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) ToupperCept: Ensure toupper form works
 Test  tests/acceptance/ToupperCept.php
 Step  See "CONVERT ME TO UPPERCASE"
 Fail  Failed asserting that   /toupper.php
-->
--> contains "convert me to uppercase".

Scenario Steps:

 6. $I->see("CONVERT ME TO UPPERCASE")
 5. $I->amOnSubdomain("toupper.php")
 4. $I->click("Convert")
 3. $I->fillField("my_string","convert me to uppercase")
 2. $I->see("Can you see me?")
 1. $I->amOnPage("index.php")


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to solve this? I appreciate it!

**UPDATE**

Upon messing around with the test, that when I write an assertion looking for the text in uppercase on toupper.php, EX) $I->see('SOMETHING'); , the test fails. It seems that if the test fails at some point, all other assertions fail. Even when I comment out the failed assertion, all previous assertion fail upon running the test again. So confused!!

**UPDATE2**

Sorry for the multiple updates, but messing around a bit more, I switched browsers for webdriver from firefox to chrome. All my tests are passing flawlessly everytime. Strange that only having issues with firefox.

Comment: You don't need amOnSubdomain.

Comment: @Naktibalda, I commented out the amOnSubdomain, but the test still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a `$I->pauseExecution();` in your test code just before the failing line.  Then you can easily see what is happening in the browser window just before the fail.  Possibly you are having an issue with Firefox retaining data in the form.